# How to create a new entity with default values if not passed?

Tags: entities

Hello everyone how are you?

I created a new configEntity called Modal with 3 fields:

1. Label
2. Body
3. Auto Open

To create a new Modal I'm using this code:

```
$modal = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('modal')->create();

$modal->setLabel('Modal Title');
$modal->setBody('Modal Content');
$modal->setAutoOpen(TRUE);
$modal->save();
```

OK! It works!

But now I don't want to pass "auto-open" and I this value with TRUE as default. Like this:

```
$modal = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('modal')->create();
        
$modal->setLabel('Modal Title');
$modal->setBody('Modal Content');
$modal->save();
```

Note that there is no "Auto-Open" and it inserts a new Modal with "auto-open" = FALSE

My goal is; if you don't pass "auto-open" this field is filled with TRUE by default.

Do you know how can we do this?

Thank you so much, everyone

Comment: There already seems to be a default value `FALSE`?! How did you create the config entity?

Comment: I didn't define any default value for this field. I don't know how can I do this. 

This is the code: 
https://git.drupalcode.org/project/modal_page/-/blob/4.0.x/src/Entity/Modal.php

Do you know how can I define this field with TRUE as default?

Answer (score 3):

For entities in general, set default values by adding preCreate() to your entity class:

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function preCreate(EntityStorageInterface $storage_controller, array &$values) {
    parent::preCreate($storage_controller, $values);
    $values += [
      'auto_open' => TRUE,
    ];
  }
```

---

In this specific case, define a class property with the same name as the field, which defaults to TRUE:

```
  /**
   * Auto Open.
   *
   * @var bool
   */
  protected $auto_open = TRUE;
```

Comment: And that it gets set to `FALSE` as in the OP when omitted is because it's a Boolean and it simply is the default for Booleans?

Comment: @leymannx, I did answer to the question title in general, for all entities. But I'm now seeing what you are referring to. In the linked code example of a config entity class the properties look a bit weird. Camel case for snake cased fields and without default, so initializing as NULL. So there are two reasons the boolean probably doesn't start with FALSE.